# boost::iostreams::gzip compressor - crc error?

Tags: boost, gzip

I am using the following code to compress a file into gzip file.
The created gzip file is corrupted

gzip -t :

```
invalid compressed data--crc error
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
const char *filename = "/home/username/Desktop/temp/data.csv";
const char *gzFilename = "/home/username/Desktop/temp/data.csv.gz";

std::ifstream inStream(filename, std::ios_base::in);
std::ofstream outStream(gzFilename, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

boost_io::filtering_streambuf<boost_io::input> compressingBuf;
compressingBuf.push(boost_io::gzip_compressor());
compressingBuf.push(inStream);

boost_io::copy(compressingBuf, outStream);
```

Comment: regardling selfconatined reproducers: http://sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact situation you may need to explicitly flush/close the output.

Also, intuitively it makes more sense to me to consider compression part of the output chain. That way you get consistent behaviour if you have multiple writes to the output, instead of risking parts to be written without compression.

Here's my rewording of the same, with some elements of style added:

- express the logic (don't repeat the file path)
- use C++ types (for string manipulation)
- don't specify redundant `std::ios` flags
- use the existing [convenience typedefs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp)

```
std::string const filename = "/home/username/Desktop/temp/data.csv";

{
    std::ofstream outStream(filename + ".gz", std::ios::binary);

    boost_io::filtering_ostreambuf compressingBuf;
    compressingBuf.push(boost_io::gzip_compressor());
    compressingBuf.push(outStream);

    {
        std::ifstream inStream(filename);
        copy(inStream, compressingBuf);
        outStream.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. 
I tried the code above - still having the same "invalid compressed data--crc error"

Comment: Perhaps you can share a self-contained example program that shows the problem. From the code you show it looks like it should only be around 20 lines of code.

Comment: I switched to use 
[https://github.com/mapbox/gzip-hpp](https://github.com/mapbox/gzip-hpp)